# symfony request returns only one request

Tags: twig, symfony

i am working with symfony 3 and twig. I take DNS info from a API. But i can never know how many rows it will be. So here is the problem lets say domain www.example.com has 3 DNS's when i request get form my controller i only get the last DNS back from the form.

---

twig:

```
{% if dnsinfo is defined %}
    <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="/setdns">
    {% if dnsinfo is not empty %}
        {% for dns in dnsinfo %}
            <div class="row " >
                <div class="input-group col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" id="dns" name="dns" value="{{ dns.1 }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 input-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" style="width:100%;">
                        <option value="notselected" selected disabled>* Select a type</option>
                        <option value="A"{% if dns.2 == 'A' %} selected{% endif %}>A</option>
                        <option value="AAAA"{% if dns.2 == 'AAAA' %} selected{% endif %}>AAAA</option>
                        <option value="CNAME"{% if dns.2 == 'CNAME' %} selected{% endif %}>CNAME</option>
                        <option value="MX"{% if dns.2 == 'MX' %} selected{% endif %}>MX</option>
                        <option value="SOA"{% if dns.2 == 'SOA' %} selected{% endif %}>SOA</option>
                        <option value="TXT"{% if dns.2 == 'TXT' %} selected{% endif %}>TXT</option>
                        <option value="SRV"{% if dns.2 == 'SRV' %} selected{% endif %}>SRV</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" id="content" name="content" value="{{ dns.3 }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-1">
                    <input type="text" id="ttl" name="ttl" value="{{ dns.4 }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="text" id="prio" name="prio" value="{{ dns.5 }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="divider" style="">

        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save">
        <a href="/registereddomain" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

---

symfony controller:

```
$this->pre($request->request->get('dns'));
$API = $this->connect();
$dns =  array(
    'domain'    => $request->request->get('domain'),
    'extension' => $request->request->get('ext'),
    'dnsdata'   => serialize( array(
        1 => array(
            'name'      => $request->request->get('dns'),
            'type'      => $request->request->get('type'),
            'content'   => $request->request->get('content'),
            'ttl'       => $request->request->get('ttl'),
            'prio'      => $request->request->get('prio')
        )
    ))
);

$API->prepare('dns', $dns);
```

Of course i know a solution. Working with numbers behind the fields name1 name2 etc. But there must be a better way to do this right? What i am trying to get is if i print my request:

> [dns] => array (array with all the DNS's i send in my form)

this is what is inside form data
https://gyazo.com/ebd558ba7f1ef8e1bfbe86e115bbb1e
as you can see it hold all the data i need yet with `$request->request->get()` i can only take the last one.
So my question is how to get all the data out?

vardump and the form that returns all the fields https://gyazo.com/0b9725ba8e298c6f59f343d3d5a548c7

---

**sollution**:

I ended up working with numbers so i can know how many fields are send from the api. And then looping to all of the fields

```
      {% if dnsinfo is defined %}
                        {% set i=0 %}

                        <form class="form-inline" method="post" id="form" action="/setdns">
                            <input value="{{ domain }}" hidden name="domain" id="domain">
                            <input value="{{ ext }}" hidden name="ext" id="ext">
                        {% if dnsinfo is not empty %}
                            {% for dns in dnsinfo %}
                                <div class="row " >
                                    <div class="input-group col-xs-3">
                                        <input type="text" id="dns{{ i }}" name="dns{{ i }}" value="{{ dns.1 }}" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2 input-group">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="type{{ i }}" name="type{{ i }}" style="width:100%;">
                                            <option value="notselected" selected disabled>* Select a type</option>
                                            <option value="A"{% if dns.2 == 'A' %} selected{% endif %}>A</option>
                                            <option value="AAAA"{% if dns.2 == 'AAAA' %} selected{% endif %}>AAAA</option>
                                            <option value="CNAME"{% if dns.2 == 'CNAME' %} selected{% endif %}>CNAME</option>
                                            <option value="MX"{% if dns.2 == 'MX' %} selected{% endif %}>MX</option>
                                            <option value="SOA"{% if dns.2 == 'SOA' %} selected{% endif %}>SOA</option>
                                            <option value="TXT"{% if dns.2 == 'TXT' %} selected{% endif %}>TXT</option>
                                            <option value="SRV"{% if dns.2 == 'SRV' %} selected{% endif %}>SRV</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <input type="text" id="content{{ i }}" name="content{{ i }}" value="{{ dns.3 }}" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                                        <input type="text" id="ttl{{ i }}" name="ttl{{ i }}" value="{{ dns.4 }}" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <input type="text" id="prio{{ i }}" name="prio{{ i }}" value="{{ dns.5 }}" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr class="divider" style="">
                                {% set i = i + 1 %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="$('#form').attr('action','/setdns{{ i }}')" value="Save">
                            <a href="/registereddomain" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
```

as you can see in my button i use jquery to send the number to my controller

```
   /**
 * @Route("/setdns{i}", name="setdns", requirements={"i": "\d+"})
 */
public function setdns(Request $request, $i = false) {

    $API = new Whoisdomainmodify();
    $API = $API->connect();

    for ($x=0; $x < $i; $x++) {
        $dns =  array(
            'domain'    =>  $request->request->get('domain'),
            'extension' =>  $request->request->get('ext'),
            'dnsdata'   => serialize(array(
                1 => array(
                    'name'      => $request->request->get('dns'.$x),
                    'type'      => $request->request->get('type'.$x),
                    'content'   => $request->request->get('content'.$x),
                    'ttl'       => $request->request->get('ttl'.$x),
                    'prio'      => $request->request->get('prio'.$x)
                )
            ))
        );
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($dns);

        $API->prepare('dns', $dns);
        // $API->execute();
        // $API->fetch();
    }

    $this->addFlash('Success', 'DNS successfully changed');

    return $this->redirectToRoute('registereddomain');

}
```

if there is a better way to do this please tell me. Because i send all my form data see gyazo.

Comment: The gyazo link you include doesn't work. Also can you do a `{{ dump(dnsinfo) }}` so we can see what is inside it. Using `{{ dns.1 }}` doesn't seem like the best way to call it.

Comment: edited it i am going to work on the numbers behind the fields now sins its a for each loop @AlvinBunk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you know that the for loop in Twig has variables:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

for example you could use:

```
{{ dns.loop.index0 }}
```

or something along those lines. Try it out. Twig is very powerful, if you get familiar with it, it might save you a lot of coding. I'm not sure if this is an answer, but it might help you out.

Comment: give me some time i might check this out on the monday even i dont have time now i am realy sorry

Comment: i checked it out sorry for the late reaction but that is not what i mean. Ur solution is in twig. I return post data to my controller and i want to use that.@Alvin Bunk